# Method Call Chaining; returning a pointer vs a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, coding-style, return

I have a `Text` class that has certain methods that return a pointer to itself, allowing calls to be chained.  (The reason being I merely like how the chaining looks and feels, honestly!)

**My question is**, which is generally better in practice (in terms of safety > versatility > performance)?   Returning and using References?  Or Returning and using Pointers?

An example of both, starting with the Pointer version:

```
class Text{
public:
    Text * position(int x, int y){
        /* do stuff */
        return this;
    }
    Text * write(const char * string);
    Text * newline();
    Text * bold(bool toggle);
    Text * etc();
    ...
};

textInstance.position(0, 0)->write("writing an ")->bold(true)->write("EXAMPLE");
textInstance.position(20, 100)
           ->write("and writing one across")
           ->newline()
           ->write("multiple lines of code");
```

versus the Reference version:

```
class Text{
public:
    Text & position(int x, int y){
        /* do stuff */
        return *this;
    }
    Text & write(const char * string);
    Text & newline();
    Text & bold(bool toggle);
    Text & etc();
    ...
};

textInstance.position(0, 0).write("writing an ").bold(true).write("EXAMPLE");
textInstance.position(20, 100)
            .write("and writing one across")
            .newline()
            .write("multiple lines of code");
```

Comment: There is no performance difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between pointers and references is quite simple: a pointer can be null, a reference can not.

Examine your API, if it makes sense for null to be able to be returned, possibly to indicate an error, use a pointer, otherwise use a reference. If you do use a pointer, you should add checks to see if it's null (and such checks may slow down your code).

Here it looks like references are more appropriate.

Comment: Aw, I wasn't thinking of that.  The chance of a nullptr being returned would defeat chaining the method calls back to back.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of returning a null pointer, you could still use references and throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

It's canonical to use references for this; precedence: [`ostream::operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). Pointers and references here are, for all ordinary purposes, the same speed/size/safety.

Answer (score 2):

Since `nullptr` is never going to be returned, I recommend the reference approach. It more accurately represents how the return value will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question.

I don't see any difference w.r.t safety or versatility, since you can do the same thing with pointer or reference. I also don't think there is any visible difference in performance since references are implemented by pointers.

But I think using reference is better because it is consistent with the standard library. For example, chaining in iostream is done by reference rather than pointer.